# onClick() to open the google assistant with first message

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I made a demo app for voice/text message using Dialogflow API. And i integrated that agent with Google action. Now I want to open Google Assistant from my app upon clicking. I want to pass first message when user open google assistant.

I used this Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    String hello = "talk to my test app";
    intent.putExtra(hello,hello);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Please help!

Comment: What are you getting when you click to fire this `Intent`?

Comment: Google assistant is opening with this intent. But I want to send my first message with this intent. So my user get the first reply automatically...

Comment: You are not able to send a default query along with opening the Assistant. AFAIK that's not part of the exposed intent.

Comment: @NickFelker can you please help to solve this ? what i have to pass ?

Comment: I don't believe you can send a default query when you open the Assistant.

Comment: I setup default queries when I enabled Google assistant in dialogue flow response. But Google assistant asking for manual entry.

Comment: So I tried to open Google assistant from my app. So I can enter first query auto and GA can respond.